# Fast update RSSI bluetooth in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, rssi

On iOS to obtain received signal strength indicator (RSSI) of the connected peripherals it is necessary to call readRSSI().
In [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1519111-readrssi) it says that :

"On iOS and tvOS, when you call this method to retrieve the RSSI of the peripheral while connected to the central manager, the peripheral calls the **peripheral(_:didReadRSSI:error:)** method of its delegate object, which includes the RSSI value as a parameter."

I need to update this value frequently, so I called the previous method in this way

```
 rssi_timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.004 , repeats: true) {
        [unowned self] _ in
        for connected in self.connectedPoints {
            connected.peripheral.readRSSI()
        }
```

but  **peripheral(_:didReadRSSI:error:)** method is called approximately once per second. Is there a way to get it updated more frequently?

Comment: This feels like a feature of Core Bluetooth to perhaps preserve battery life. Currently investigating so will report back any findings and whether I can poll RSSI more frequently than once per second.

Comment: UPDATE: Yeah, can't obtain RSSI number any more frequently than roughly every 1 second unfortunately (when using Core Bluetooth APIs).